# What wil happen when Reynolds number equals unity?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

we all know that reynolds number gives the relation between the inertia force and viscous force. So if reynolds number becomes unity(exactly 1), does it mean inertia force equals viscous force?
and what does it physically sigifies?..practically good or bad..??

Comment: All capital nicks look bad, I suggest to change to "Sujay D Dubal".

Answer (score 1):

In Navier-Stokes equation, there is a term representing acceleration of fluid particle and a term representing viscous force on fluid particle (there are other terms too). $Re$ is a measure of how important one term is with respect to another. $Re\ll 1$ means that viscous term is dominant compared to acceleration (usually called inertial term), and so we may work with a simplified Navier-Stokes equation in which acceleration term is ignored. If $Re\approx 1$ then none of the two terms may be ignored. In this case since viscous forces are comparable to inertial force on fluid particle, the resulting flow would be laminar.

There is nothing inherently good or bad about a laminar flow. In most applications and natural phenomena it is rarely the case that $Re$ is close to one. Usually $Re\gg 1$ and the flow would be turbulent.